# Logon to a remote system via a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first extension and I suspect the way I've gone about structuring the order of calling code is not completely right. I would appreciate pointers please - hopefully I'm fairly close as it has taken weeks of study, trial and error to get this far :-) XMLHttpRequest does not seem to call the system and the extension crashes a lot.

In the popup.html, there's a SignIn button which opens the 'popup' form signin.html via a listener in background.js. The signin page contains a form with a username & password inputs, and a signin button. Clicking this button calls signin.js to pickup the data from the form, and calls a routine in background.js to connect to the system (could this be the issue - since this was all kicked off from the background.js in the first place???)

In the code,e I'm connecting to Google so I know I have a website that works - I'll deal with the logon part later. Thanks.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "logon test",
  "description": "logon test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2, 

  "icons": { "128": "images/logon.png" },

  "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/logon.png",
        "default_title": "logon test",
        "default_popup": "popup.html" },

   "background": {
         "scripts": ["background.js"],
         "persistent": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "background",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "http://www.google.com/*",
    "https://www.google.com/*"
   ]

}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id = "signin">Sign In</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
function onSignIn() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({'action' : 'signin', 'url' : 
    '/signin.html'});
} //onSignIn

document.getElementById('signin').addEventListener('click', onSignIn);  


**signin.html:**
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input name="userid" type="text" id="userid" value="User ID">
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <script src="signin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**signin.js:**

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgWindow) {
        bgWindow.signIn(password, userid); //background page
        window.close();     // Close dialog
    });
};
```

**background.js:**

```
function signIn(inPass, inUserid) { //called from signin.html popup

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr === null){
        alert("Unable to create request");
        } else {
            xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=helloworld', 
             true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                alert("result here" + resp);
                } //readystate
            };
        }
    xhr.send(null);
} //signin


// button functionality - called from popup.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
 {
    if (request.action === 'signin') {         
            chrome.tabs.create({ 
                        url: chrome.extension.getURL(request.url),
                        active: false
                    }, function(tab) {
                                chrome.windows.create({
                                        tabId: tab.id,
                                        type: 'popup',
                                        focused: true,
                                        left: 500,
                                        top: 20,
                                        width: 450,
                                        height: 200});
                        }); //tab
    } //if
return true;
});
```

Comment: 1. `XMLHttpRequest does not seem to call the system` - the background page has its own devtools and console accessible from chrome://extensions page when [x] developer mode checkbox is enabled. 2. Why do you create an empty unused popup window? 3. What exactly "crashes a lot" mean and is there a certain trigger for the crash? 4. I'm not sure it's a good idea to have `signIn()` in a non-persistent background page as it may unload before you receive the response. Move it to a separate js file and simply include it on pages that need it.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm. [4] I've moved the code into a separate js as you suggest. I was thinking that the non-persistent page would be an issue. I've jiggled all the code around and now it appears to be working. [2] POPUP.HTML has a button on it which triggered the sign in.

Now all I have to do is package up a username and password into JSON format, send it to the webservice, and process the return! :-P

Thanks again.